# Why there are no 2v2 pro tournaments?

Tags: starcraft-2

I enjoy a lot following starcraft 2 tournaments, both by downloading replays and by watching commentaries.

I noticed though that all tournaments are 1v1.

Is there any particular reason for not having non-1v1 tournaments?

I guess there might be some like:

- hard to follow action
- problems in organising team and matches
- all-alone fame hunger (*don't think so*)

But all are blind shots. Any more information regarding this?

Comment: Paging @tezenes to rant about the fundamental imbalance of team play in Starcraft. The tl;dr version is that there is no competitive 2v2 because 2v2, by it's nature, is not competitive.

Comment: 2v2 can be very fun to watch if it's cast well, but since it isn't as balanced or as true a test of skill as 1v1, people probably shy away from it as "pro tournament" material.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While there are still 2vs2 tournaments, they are small and gain no where near the attention the 1on1 tournaments do.  1on1 tournaments are exciting because of the natural game balance.

(ideally) Any of the races can win and are only capped by Human potential.  2vs2 doesn't share this balance.  The game has not been balanced for 2vs2, so certain strategies emerge as very very powerful (potentially unbeatable) abuse of the game mechanics that aren't possible in a 1on1.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Its important to note that the Korean scene has always been strong with team based tournaments.  While balance was the reason Broodwars 2v2 never reached the height of 1v1, it still became prominent.

Comment: citation for game not being balanced for 2v2?

Answer (score 1):

2v2 is a very different dynamic from 1v1. However there are some pro 2v2 team games, but what your really watching is how well they work together as a team (like watching a Hockey game) versus how well the individual player is at their game. In 2v2, both players have to properly compliment each other which isn't actually as exciting as watching a 1v1.

Comment: And yet, hockey is fun to watch somehow. =) Anyone have a link to these rumored 2v2 tournaments?

Comment: @Wikiwocket http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&q=2vs2+starcraft+2+tournaments&aq=f&aqi=&aql=f&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=4488cb887e893d25

Comment: the Machinamia invitational (http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Machinima_Realm_Invitational) tournament featured some 2v2 with top level players, and I believe the upcoming EG Masters cup series will have 2v2 games too have a look here: - http://mcs.myeg.net/